# Ajax PHP updation not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to update one field through ajax which is not working. below is the code

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeStatus(changeStatus,userId) {
        var data="changeStatus="+changeStatus+"&userId="+userId;
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'myfunctions.php',
            data:data,
            success:function() {
                alert('Updated');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

php:

```
<?php
function changeStatus($changeStatus,$userId){
    $userId=$_GET['userId'];
    $userStatus=$_GET['userStatus'];
    switch($userStatus) {
        case "1":
            $changeStatus=0;
            break;
        case "0":
            $changeStatus=1;
            break;
        default:
            $changeStatus="";
    }
    $Query="UPDATE blog_users SET blog_user_status='$changeStatus' WHERE                 blog_user_id='$userId'";
    $Result=mysql_query($Query);
}

if(isset($_GET['userId']) && isset($_GET['userStatus'])) {
    changeStatus($changeStatus,$userId);
}
?>
```

and here is how i call the function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeStatus($changeStatus,$userId)"><?php echo $action; ?></a>
```

Just to let know that i tried this only in php by passing get values through href. and it was working...

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="changeStatus($changeStatus,$userId)"><?php echo $action; ?></a> i bet this is not working. You are calling a variable outside php ( $changestatus $userId )

Comment: I had done this same thing while deleting record. It was working ...

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Can you please answer my problem?

Comment: What does your javascript console say?

Comment: :S i dint get it what are u asking

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeStatus(<?php echo $changeStatus; ?>,<?php echo $userId; ?>)"><?php echo $action; ?></a>
```

Try with that

Comment: Tried with this also, but no response. its just adding a # with url :\

Answer (score 0):

So you are not using the right get variables. In the javascript you set the get variables to `changeStatus` and `userId`

```
var data="changeStatus="+changeStatus+"&userId="+userId;
```

However in your PHP you get `userId` and `userStatus`

```
$userId=$_GET['userId'];
$userStatus=$_GET['userStatus'];
```

So `$userStatus` will never be set since it should `$_GET['userStatus']`

Since it is empty your query will always look like:

```
"UPDATE blog_users SET blog_user_status='' WHERE blog_user_id='$userId'";
```